# Bootstrap Modal Background issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap modal background screen doesn't work properly when any element is dynamically added . To be clear after some extent the screen goes white. for better understanding i have even uploaded a picture [image]

Answer (score 1):

I would double check to make sure all your divs are closed in your HTML. What was the out come when you inspected the elements on the page?

Would prob be easier if you added your code alongside the picture.

Comment: I cant give out my code company policies but to make sure each and every div in my html is closed . I have posted a picture of it look at the part where background screen(black) changes to transparent or say ends there .Any solution to that ?

Comment: @KalebereGaurav could be an ordering issue? Try moving your bootstrap CDN/ script tag to the bottom of your body tag. Make sure all tags are properly closed.

Comment: @ Jay I tried all things you suggested , no luck yet.

Comment: It is difficult to help not seeing the code. Are you using a gem or a CDN?